# MySQL Update Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a simple mysql table that contains an id, firstname, lastname and an email.  The table creation code is as follows:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE users
(
   id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
   PRIMARY KEY(id),
   firstname varchar(20),   
   lastname varchar(20),
   email varchar(40)
)";
```

Table creation works and I've had no issues.  My problem comes when I try to update the table, and the user information.

My update query looks as follows:

```
mysql_select_db(dustin,$con);

$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."',lastname='".$_GET['ln']."',email='".$_GET['emadd']"'";

$sherlock=mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Essentially, I open a file that allows the user to edit the stored information in form elements and then when the update query runs it should alter the information contained within the table.

mysql_error(); shows no output and the UPDATE query fails.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Print the $sql variable and see what kind of query it shows. Also, please look at topics about SQL injection on SO because your current query can be hijacked quite easily.

Comment: where is the where clause for your sql?

Comment: Check my answer out. It will help you much.

Comment: you missed code after $_GET['emadd']

Comment: Do not forget to accept answers on the site. If you do not, users will think you do not care and might even avoid answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."', lastname='".$_GET['ln']."',email='".$_GET['emadd']"'";
```

Let's see... do this.

```
$sql="UPDATE `users` SET firstname='{$_GET['fn']}', lastname='{$_GET['ln']}', email='{$_GET['emadd']}'";
```

BUT I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS!!!

Clean your data first with mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent SQL injection!

For example:

```
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fn']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ln']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['emadd']);

$sql="UPDATE `users` SET `firstname`='$firstname', `lastname`='$lastname', `email`='$email' WHERE ...";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Also, where's your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Welcome to SO, by the way. :D

Comment: Thanks Ken, I appreciate the injection tips, I'm just now starting to learn about that.

Comment: Np, also, cleaning the data removes the need for periods and what not, as it is set to a variable. When security is important, this is the preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with php, but you may be missing a `period` here:

```
email='".$_GET['emadd']
----------------------/\
```

You're also missing a `WHERE` clause, so you will update all of the records.

Comment: Im not asking the question, btw :3

Answer (score 1):

In your query WHERE condition is misssing...

every update query require where condition like

WHERE id=n  n can be anything

and also error in query u miss . after $_GET['emadd']

Comment: Working on the WHERE now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error `email='".$_GET['emadd']"'";` right here, you forgot a dot before `"'"`. Also this is hideous code. Don't use `mysql` use `mysqli` or `PDO` and prepared statements to avoid SQL injection security holes and make your code much more readable.

Comment: Thanks chx, reading up on mysqli now, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

in your code the where codition missing as well in the last of the code you did the mistake your query should be

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."', lastname='".$_GET['ln']."', email='".$_GET['emadd']."' where condition";
```

instead of

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."',lastname='".$_GET['ln']."',email='".$_GET['emadd']"'";
```

you miss a `.` operator in the end of your query

Comment: Thanks Jogesh, I added the . in and it works well!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a WHERE-part in your query, unles of course you wan't to update all records.

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."',lastname='".$_GET['ln']."',email='".$_GET['emadd']."' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
```

Also, have you polulated the table already? You can change INSERT to [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) and that will work with both new and updated lines.

```
$sql="REPLACE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."',lastname='".$_GET['ln']."',email='".$_GET['emadd']."' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
```