# UPDATE Query in MySQL using WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following UPDATE query and having no succes:

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."',lastname='".$_GET['ln']."',email='".$_GET['emadd']."' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
```

mysql_error(); returns no error, though I'm sure this is a syntax issue.

If you can help me clean this up with an explanation to help me learn where I went wrong it would be much appreciated!

To give a larger point of reference, here is the table creation code:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE users
(
id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
firstname varchar(20),  
lastname varchar(20),
email varchar(40)
)";
```

And here is the entire code from my updater.php which runs the update query on the table:

```
mysql_select_db(dustin,$con);
$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='".$_GET['fn']."',lastname='".$_GET['ln']."',email='".$_GET['emadd']."' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
$sherlock=mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

echo $sql returns the following:

```
UPDATE users SET firstname='Mike',lastname='Wilson',email='mike@eyeball.com' WHERE id =
```

Does this mean my id is not getting passed over?

To see it live in action, go to 24.77.236.155/dustin/Assignment2/users.php and click edit to play with the query.  Also, 24.77.236.155/dustin/Assignment2/add.htm is available to add users to the table.

Comment: Print out the sql as it will make it easier to debug. Also, you should be using bind variables - this is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: `."' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];` to `."' where id='" . $GET['id] . "'";`

Comment: you say mysql_error returns no error...does mysql_query return true or false?

Comment: if id is an integer quotes are not required

Comment: I know this is off-topic and I may be down-voted for this.. but @DustinJames **---putting your `$_GET` variable data directly into a query is one of the most dangerous, harmful, unsecured things you can do to your site if you're not validating the contents of those values---** I hope you can do something about this.. [ reason for outburst ] -> [SQL Injection!](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) :(

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Print your value for `$_GET['id']` and if that looks okay, post more of your code. There may be more at play here...

Comment: can you share your table creation sql as well?

Comment: Does anything at all get updated in the table?

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252539/mysql-update-query-in-php It is the same apart from the specification of `WHERE` which, in this case, doesn't warrant a new question

Comment: Also, can you show us some sample values that you're using to update? I'm wondering if any of them have a single quote in them. If they do, then nonym wasn't "off-topic" at all and SQL Injection is your whole issue.

Comment: @BrendanBullen - sorry for the duplicate, new here, not entirely sure how to approach follow up questions.  I will try to do things under the same question to prevent duplication in the future.

Comment: Updated the code above to provide a greater frame of reference.

Comment: And it's working, had to pass the id through.  Created a hidden form element to do so and it works.  Thanks for the help, sometimes I stare at something for many moons thinking it's syntax, this saved me a headache.

Comment: @nonym: comments can't be downvoted, only upvoted.

Comment: @MarcB.. oh, right! it was just a comment, not an answer.. my bad.. DustinJames -- I suppose your professor might have wanted to take things slowly.. and then help you advance as you progress.. sorry for the outburst though it was not my intention to be offensive ... cheers!

Comment: @MarcB no worries at all, if anything, it gives me a better idea of what to learn in order to progress, thanks for the SQL Injection Link, reading it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query seems fine, I am assuming it is not updating the table?

One way to debug this is to echo the $sql in next line to see what values you are receiving for GET variables and the actual query that is being passed to the database.

```
echo $sql;
```

Comment: echo $sql results are as follows:  UPDATE users SET firstname='Mike',lastname='Wilson',email='mike@eyeball.com' WHERE id =   Does that mean my id is not being passed?

Comment: @DustinJames can't you see it in the address tring in your browser?

Comment: Yep, just an id not passing through, created a hidden form element and it works, thanks, I would have stared at that forever thinking it was syntax.  I will have to remember to echo my sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

always run all your queries at least this way

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or trigger_error(mysql_error(). " ".$sql);
```

unlike some wild guesses from answers here, it will give you EXACT and compplete picture of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Colonel, I will start doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes in the where bit

i.e.

```
...where id='" . $GET['id] . "'";
```

Also you have a security issue by using $GET without checking those values.

Comment: if id is an integer quotes are not required

Comment: @julien - I was assuming that since it is not working then id is not an integer.

Comment: @EdHeal If that were the case, `mysql_error()` should show a syntax error